# How to show a sympy equation in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, sympy

Is it possible to show an equation from sympy in matplotlib? Let's suppose that I have this simple integral expression

[image: 1]

How can I show the integral as shown in "Out [2]" in the xlabel of a graph in matplotlib?

Comment: Please [include your code as text, not as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it can be done. Matplotlib [supports TeX for text](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/text/mathtext.html) by surrounding specific text syntax between dollar signs. And sympy can export an expression to latex syntax, so you don't have to do any manual parsing.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sympy as sym
from sympy.printing import latex
    
x = sym.symbols('x')
f = sym.Integral(sym.sqrt(1/x), x)
plt.plot([])
plt.xlabel(f'${latex(f)}$')
plt.show()
```

Output

[image: 1]

Comment: And interestingly, this seems to render faster than when manually installing latex and using the `text.usetex : True` method as described here: https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/text/usetex.html#usetex